# Getting connection details in Sencha Touch fails: TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am building an app using Sencha Touch 2. According to their [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.0.2/#!/api/Ext.device.Connection), and multiple other sources on the web ([1](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?228772-how-to-check-which-type-of-wifi-connection-in-ipad), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11357301/how-to-check-which-type-of-wifi-connection-in-ipad-using-sencha-touch2)), I can get the connection type by using `Ext.device.Connection.getType()`

But on this line:

```
var connection = Ext.device.Connection.getType();
```

I get the following error on an Android device:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined
```

When running in Google Chrome on my desktop computer, it always returns null. Although, if I use the javascript console in Chrome to call `Ext.device.Connection.isOnline()`, this returns true, and getType() now starts returning 'Unknown connection' instead of null.

This is the relevant part of my config.xml (probably don't need all of these, but I have tried with only the two first and the two last, without changes):

```
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device" />
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation" />
<feature name="Device">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.device.Device" />
</feature>
<feature name="NetworkStatus">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.NetworkManager" />
</feature>
```

All other Cordova functionality works as expected, so I believe the framework is installed correctly. What am I doing wrong, and/or what can I do to figure this out?

Comment: Check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25672502/phonegap-network-connection-cannot-read-property-type-of-undefined

Comment: Thanks, that got me on the right track!

Comment: cool! You can always express your thankfulness through casting some upvotes :)

Comment: If you write an answer, I can also mark it as correct. Otherwise, I'll just use my own. ;)

Comment: :) I meant on the other thread (the one i linked in). Didn't want to duplicate those answers here, and anyway it looks like it wasn't enough to solve your problem on it's own, it only put you in the right directon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the answer was that I needed the following plugin:
http://build.phonegap.com/plugins/626

I had this plugin in my config.xml file, but it had disappeard from the plugins folder, probably due to the project moving from person to person. The solution was to remove this plugin and re-add it a couple of times (it didn't work the first time), and then everything worked again.